# Java MVC JSP get Connection and Values from JavaBean

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, get, connection

I was trying to get the values (List productList = data.getProductList();) in ShowProductCatalog.jsp from the JavaBean ProductDataBean.java. I'm getting the error nullpointerexception. Please help! Your help will be much appreciated.

*edited: I realised the connection I'm getting in ProductDataBean.java in getProductList() is null. Now the question is, how can I make the changes to insert the value? If I put the whole connection in getProductList(), there is error message. "No Suitable Driver found."

```
      **ShowProductCatalog.jsp**


    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ page import = "java.util.*" import="cart.*,java.net.*,java.text.*"%>
     <jsp:useBean id="data" scope="session" class="cart.ProductDataBean" />

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <%
        List productList = data.getProductList();
        Iterator prodListIterator = productList.iterator();
        %>



      **ProductDataBean.java**


package cart;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ProductDataBean implements Serializable{

    private static Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement addRecord, getRecords;

    public ProductDataBean(){
        try{
            // Step1: Load JDBC Driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Step 2: Define Connection URL
            String connURL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlineshop?user=root&password=teck1577130713"; 
            // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
            connection =   DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return connection;
    }
    public ArrayList getProductList() throws SQLException{
        ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
        while (results.next()){
            DVD movie = new DVD();
            movie.setMovie(results.getString("movieName"));
            movie.setRating(results.getString("movieRate"));
            movie.setYear(results.getString("movieYear"));
            movie.setPrice(results.getDouble("moviePrice"));
            productList.add(movie);
        }
        return productList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your build path mySql driver is added. and please add exception to the question what you getting, then easily can answer.

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
```

you can get it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

have a look this SO [How to avoid java code in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

I suggest you to use `Servlets` instead of writing java code in jsp.
If you write code in servlets then easily you can test/debug your code.

To answer: `how can I make the changes to insert the value?`

Create a PreparedStatement obj with sql insert query and call `[executeUpdate()][3]` to perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations.

Add this piece of code in your `ProductDataBean` class to add a new record to table.

```
    public static void addRecord(DVD dvd) throws SQLException{
                PreparedStatement pStatement = 
getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into products(movieName, movieRate, movieYear, moviePrice) values(?,?,?,?)");
                pStatement.setString(1, dvd.getMovie());
                pStatement.setString(2, dvd.getRating());
                pStatement.setString(3, dvd.getYear());
                pStatement.setDouble(4, dvd.getPrice());
                pStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
```

Make your `DVD` class a POJO like

```
package cart;

public class DVD {

    private String movie;
    private String rating;
    private String year;
    private Double price;

    public DVD(){}  

    public DVD(String movie, String rating, String year, Double price) {        
        this.movie = movie;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
    }



    public String getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(String movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DVD [movie=" + movie + ", rating=" + rating + ", year=" + year
                + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }

}
```

And in your jsp page call servlet url pattern to perform GET and POST, and to render all products in jsp user standard tag lib `jstl1.2.jar` you get it from [here](https://jstl.java.net/download.html)
So replace your jsp file with:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<c:url value="/Product" var="pdctServletUrl"/>
Product Page
<form method="post" action="${pdctServletUrl}">
    <h4>Enter New Movie details:</h4>

    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="movie"/>

    <label>Rating</label>
    <input type="text" name="rating"/>

    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="text" name="year"/>

    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="price"/>

    <input type="submit" value="save movie"/>
</form>
<br/>
To get a list of products click 
<a href="${pdctServletUrl}">Get Products</a>   

<c:if test="${not empty products}">
<h4>Available Products.</h4>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Movie Name</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="pd">
        <tr>
            <td>${pd.movie}</td>
            <td>${pd.rating}</td>
            <td>${pd.year}</td>
            <td>${pd.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

A servlet to handle `GET` and `POST` request's and transfering data to client etc.

Product.java

```
package cart;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Product
 */
@WebServlet("/Product")
public class Product extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ProductDataBean pDataBean = new ProductDataBean();

    public Product() {
        super();        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<Product> products;
        try {
            products = pDataBean.getProductList();  // Obtain all products.
            request.setAttribute("products", products); // Store products in request scope.
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response); // Forward to JSP page to display them in a HTML table.
        } catch (SQLException e) {                  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        String movie = req.getParameter("movie");
        String rating = req.getParameter("rating");
        String year = req.getParameter("year");
        Double price = Double.valueOf(req.getParameter("price"));

        if(movie!=null && rating!=null && year!=null && price!=null)
            try {
                ProductDataBean.addRecord(new DVD(movie, rating, year, price));
            } catch (SQLException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

}
```

I think this may help you to understand.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)

Comment: did you use any IDE like eclipse ?

Comment: @De De De De clean your server work directory and restart server, re run your application.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your time and effort to write this post.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP page is working properly and there is no mistake. Check your database and confirm that you have rows inside the products table. Null pointer exception occurs because the method `getProductList()` is not returning an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I realised the connection I'm getting in ProductDataBean.java in getProductList() is null. Now the question is, how can I make the changes to insert the value? If I put the whole connection in getProductList(), there is error message

Comment: Something like "No suitable driver found"